# Redirect urls to pages on another domain with whm/cpanel vps?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel, whm

My client's website was previously running on 3 separate shared hosted wordpress sites, but has now been brought together into one site on hubspot. The wordpress sites are still running for the sole purpose of redirecting traffic to the relevant page on the new site. The client wants to get rid of the shared hosting wordpress sites, but keep the redirects. They have a vps on godaddy available, which they want to point the old domains to and use to redirect the traffic. I have a list of redirects between the old domains and the new domain which need to be set up.

I have tried initiating a new cPanel account for one of the old site's domains with whm, and then setting up each redirect individually through there. My questions are

1. will this approach work? Is there a better one?
2. Can I make this a lot less manual by using the htaccess file to bulk add each redirect? I want to redirect specific urls to specific paths on a different domain, but the htaccess file only seems to be able to redirect to another page on the same domain. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the best way to it is "Park a Domain" in WHM/CPANEL.
This allows you to have multiple domains for the same website/application